# Oracle 12 equal and not equal (=, !=, <>) behavior about nvarchar2 working problem

Tags: oracle, null, varchar2

In oracle an empty varchar2 and null are treated the same because Oracle internally changes empty string to NULL values.
Please consider  following example :

```
--1- create table
CREATE TABLE persons(
    person_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(50)  ,
    last_name VARCHAR2(50)  ,
    PRIMARY KEY(person_id)
); 

--2-insert sample data
insert into persons (first_name,last_name) values('n1','l1');
insert into persons (first_name,last_name) values('n2',null);
insert into persons (first_name,last_name) values('n3','');
insert into persons (first_name) values('n4');
```

the following query has result :

```
select * from persons where last_name is null;

PERSON_ID FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME                                        
    2      n2                                                                                                   
    3      n3                                                                                                   
    4      n4
```

and

```
 select * from persons where last_name is not null;
    PERSON_ID FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME                          
        1      n1                  l1
```

My question :

1-Why this queries result are “no rows selected”

```
select * from persons where last_name =''; --   no rows selected
select * from persons where last_name !=''; --  no rows selected
```

2-**More important question** is wonderful behavior for the following query:

```
select * from persons where last_name !='' or last_name =''; --  no rows selected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-Why this queries result are “no rows selected”

Because the answer lies in your question itself.

```
select * from persons where last_name =''; -- here '' is converted to NULL
-- so last_name = NULL 
-- it will always fail as NULL can not match with other NULL also

select * from persons where last_name !=''; --  - here '' is converted to NULL
-- so last_name != NULL 
-- it will always fail as NULL can not mismatch with other NULL also
```

2-More important question is wonderful behavior for the following query:

```
select * from persons where last_name !='' or last_name =''; 
--  equal or not equal with NULL will always return false. 
-- so the result is no rows for this query also
```

Please note that in any expression if one side is `NULL`, it will always return false. (`IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` need to be used for checking null values)